# Passing data through ajax without success

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I am passing data through this code but it's not working:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Edit_we","storemanager")',
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                dataType: "json",

                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data)
            {
                alert("your data is saved")

            },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error has occured!!!");
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
  url: "service.xxx",
  type: "POST",
  data: {variable: JSON.stringify(obj)},
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data)
        {
            alert("your data is saved")

        },
   error: function () {
            alert("An error has occured!!!");
        }
});
```

for `url` provide absolute or relative path for your backed service, and use a variable to accept data from front-end.